# How to translate an object from a custom node?

Tags: python, node-editor

I want to transofrm.translate a selected object from a custom node based on the "Custom Node" template python codes.So i make a button just like the translate when you press T in the draw function.Heres is the snippet

```
 # Additional buttons displayed on the node.
def draw_buttons(self, context, layout):
    layout.label("Node settings")
    layout.prop(self, "myFloatProperty")
    #---------------------------------------------MINE------------------------------------
    col=layout.col(align=True)
    col.operator("transform.translate")
    #col.operator("transform.edge_slide", text="Slide Edge")
    #---------------------------------------------MINE------------------------------------
```

.This is what i get 
[image]

but when i press the button, only the node moves.the selected object doenst move.

How can i make it so that when i press it,it works exactly like when i press it on the T panel?